# Regex not with multi line text

Tags: php, regex

So I'm working on a project where I am building a price guide for a trading card game. Forgive the nerdiness level here. I'm pulling data from one website

```
$data = mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents("http://yugioh.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Elemental%20HERO%20Shining%20Flare%20Wingman&rvprop=content&format=php"), "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
```

then I am parsing it using a series of Regex statements.

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=\|\slore)\s+\=(.*)/', $data, $matches);
$text = $matches[1][0]; //it prints out here just fine
$text = preg_replace("/(\[\[(\w+|\s)*\|)/sx", "" , $text); //it disappears if I try to print it here
$text = preg_replace("/\[\[/", "" , $text);
$text = preg_replace("/\]\]/", "" , $text);
```

As you can see by the lines above at the second line where I grab the matches, if I follow it with a print_r statement it will print the text. On the next line if I follow it with a print statement it will not print anything. So by this logic it means the regex isn't parsing correctly. So what am I doing wrong with it? I think it has something to do with multiline but I tried that and it didn't help.

**EDIT**

Here is the text after the first pull

```
 "[[Elemental HERO Flame Wingman]]" + "[[Elemental HERO Sparkman]]"
Must be [[Fusion Summon]]ed and cannot be [[Special Summon]]ed by other ways. This card gains 300 [[ATK]] for each "[[Elemental HERO]]" card in your [[Graveyard]]. When this card [[destroy]]s a [[Monster Card|monster]] [[Destroyed by Battle|by battle]] and [[send]]s it to the Graveyard: Inflict [[Effect Damage|damage]] to your opponent equal to the ATK of the destroyed monster in the Graveyard.
```

Comment: Please provide the `text` contents after the first regex pass (i.e. `$matches[1][0]` contents).

Comment: @shA.t `s` tells the . to include newlines, and `x` covers extended comments and whitespaces. @stribizhev I have added the text

Comment: Why all the bother with that, why not use a different output format? Such as json?

Comment: @RamRaider have you tried messing around with getting wikia page data. This is the best option I have found so far, and it actually works a lot better than I thought it was, it is incredibly quick and accurate.

Comment: Fair play - Yes, I have tried before and you are right - it does tend to be a pain in the proverbial!

Comment: by any means 'x' does ignore spaces in regex pattern not match string.

Comment: @RamRaider indeed it does, I do hope they improve their API in the future to make it easier for a user to access page content swiftly

Comment: @revo yes I'm aware of this fact, what I am trying to figure out is why it is not grabbing all the text

Comment: I'm afraid if we do have such a thing `\w+*` in any regex flavor. Omit `+` sign in first `preg_replace` pattern.

Comment: Catastrophic backtracking. You need to use `$text = preg_replace("/(\[\[([\w\s]*)\|)/", "" , $text);`. Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/ASVyUL).

Comment: @stribizhev It's not catastrophic, it's an obvious error.

Comment: @revo: I can [prove my words](https://regex101.com/r/iI0uF0/1). And a catastrophic backtracking is caused by a bad regex, surely. Mark, does it work if you use the code from my demo?

Comment: @stribizhev It's an error. PCRE doesn't compile `+*` to anything. It's not about catastrophic backtracking but a perfect error.

Comment: @revo: There is no `+*` in OP's regex. Only nested quantifiers that are really a bad practice (or you can call that user error).

Comment: @stribizhev this is the correct solution, if you post it as the answer I will accept it. Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex `/(\[\[(\w+|\s)*\|)/sx` contains nested quantifiers: `\w` is used with `+` quantifier and a `*` is applied to the whole alternation group. That creates a huge amount of backtracking steps, and results in [catastrophic backtracking](https://regex101.com/r/iI0uF0/1).

The best way to avoid that issue here is through character class `[\w\s]*` (that matches 0 or more alphanumeric characters or whitespace symbols).

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/ASVyUL):

```
$s = "\"[[Elemental HERO Flame Wingman]]\" + \"[[Elemental HERO Sparkman]]\"\nMust be [[Fusion Summon]]ed and cannot be [[Special Summon]]ed by other ways. This card gains 300 [[ATK]] for each \"[[Elemental HERO]]\" card in your [[Graveyard]]. When this card [[destroy]]s a [[Monster Card|monster]] [[Destroyed by Battle|by battle]] and [[send]]s it to the Graveyard: Inflict [[Effect Damage|damage]] to your opponent equal to the ATK of the destroyed monster in the Graveyard.";
$s = preg_replace('/(\[\[([\w\s]*)\|)/', "" , $s);
echo $s;
```

Also note that you do not  need `x` modifier (since there are no comments and meaningless whitespace in the pattern itself) and the `s` modifier (since there is no `.` in the pattern).